# Emulate OS X on a Windows or Ubuntu PC?

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, emulator

Is there emulating software to run or emulate OS X on a Windows or Ubuntu PC. I am writing a python script to make a friend's job easier(with her company's ok) and while it's supposed to be multi platform, I would really like to try it out before hand. However she has a Mac and I have only Windows or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifehacker has an excellent guide on running a [virtualized OSX inside Windows](http://lifehacker.com/#!5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows) with Virtualbox.

I've tried it and it is good enough for anything that doesn't involve graphics acceleration.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Virtual Box and VMware will boot OS-X images

Comment: Could you please give a bit more detail on the procedure involved?

Comment: http://m.lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows

Comment: sry try [link] http://m.lifehacker.com/5583650/run-mac-os-x-in-virtualbox-on-windows [link]

Answer (score 2):

If it's only a fairly small script, the best way to test on OSX would probably be to run it on your friend's computer - just make it clear that it will be the first test on OSX. Unless you're doing things that are highly platform-dependent, Ubuntu will probably be close enough for testing during development - even Windows might suffice. The only suggestion I would make is to check what version of Python your friend's Mac is running. - OSX ships with a relatively old version, and doesn't update it automatically. Either update it with [an installer from the Python website](http://www.python.org/download/), or develop to the version already installed.

Even if you do get a copy of OSX and run it in a virtual machine (which, depending on where you are, may be a violation of OSX's licence), you'd still need to check things like where your friend has installed any dependancies, so you're not really saving yourself much time.